# Sinch callkit video calls always appear as audio call

Tags: ios, sinch, callkit

I'm integrating my app with CallKit and Sinch.
Every video call appears as an audio call in the CallKit native calling screen.
I have checked to receive the value `SIN_INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL` in the push payload and it's well received.

Comment: its not really supported by callkit,

Comment: Facebook Messenger displays it correctly